# Python3 script exit with any traceback?

Tags: python-3.x, traceback

I have one Python3 script that exits without any traceback from time to time.

Some said in another question that it was caused by calling sys.exit, but I am not pretty sure whether this is the case.

So how can I make Python3 script always exit with traceback, of course except when it is killed with signal 9?

Comment: If you could add the code it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the script crashed when calling some function from underlying so, and crashed without any trackback. .